# The simplest Gruntfile.coffee that will prove grunt is working?

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, gruntjs

Looking for a ground level intro to grunt, so I'd like to know what the simplest Gruntfile would be that would still let me run `grunt` at the command line and see that the grunt process is working. Then I can add functionality from there, but I'd like to start at the very beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest grunt file that will produce output (Gruntfile.coffee):

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.registerTask 'default', 'Try Logging', ->
    grunt.log.write('Running the default task')
```